# Opencv image capture from web cam has weird green/black color but camera preview shows correct image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, webcam, video-capture

I have a scene that looks in real-life like below (sample below): [image]

I have a webcam connected to RPi4 from which I now want to capture the images. I use openCV to do it using the code snippet below:

```
def capture_side_image():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    #s = time.time()

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera")
        cap.release()
        exit()

    else:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        
        # if frame is read correctly ret is True
        if not ret:
            print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
            send_response = '{"response": "Cant receive frame ;stream end?"}'

        else:    
            mtx, dist = load_coefficients(f'sideview_calibration_chessboard.yml')
            img_undistort = cv2.undistort(frame, mtx, dist, None, None)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img_undistort, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            cv2.imwrite('imagecapture_sideview.png',img)

            print('imagecapture_sideview.png completed')
            send_response = '{"response": "ok"}'

            cap.release()

            return send_response
```

however, it returns the image like below (object in the centre is changed as we made few hardware changes at the back but camera is same):
[image]

The `sideview_calibration_chessboard.yml` is just a yml file with matrices and all it does it undistortion. I have tried saving it as directly (assuming it is RGB color space), BGR2RGB color space, even HSV but none of the help.

If I simply stream the camera using:

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    #gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

it shows everything correctly. It's just when I save the image (second code above) that they are saved incorrectly.

Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but do not convert from BGR to RGB and then use OpenCV to save the image.

Comment: Already tried that @fmw42. It gave a different color tint (more bluish I guess) but not the real/desired one.

Comment: Your reference picture may be including a color profile such sRGB.icc that the video camera does not include or that OpenCV ignores.

Comment: How do I find it?

Comment: On your original reference photo, use exiftool, to see all meta data and including any profiles. Or use ImageMagick, identify -verbose on the image to see what profiles are included. For your grabbed frame, you would have to save the frame to disk and then do the same. I am not sure but PIL may also be able to do that. But I have not confirmed that.

Comment: @Sulphur Try using `cv2.imwrite('test.png', img)` just before `cv.imshow('frame', frame)`. Remove `img = cv2.cvtColor(img_undistort, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`. Can you add to your post the exact same scene (instead of different plant)? (capture it using other camera).